# cs50 recover(pset4) doesn not recover correct images

Tags: c, debugging, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2 || argc > 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover IMAGE\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char filename[8];
    BYTE arr1[512];
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    FILE *img;
    while (fread(arr1, sizeof(BYTE), 512, file) != 0)
    {
        if (arr1[0] == 0xff && arr1[1] == 0xd8 && arr1[2] == 0xff && (arr1[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0 && count == 0)
        {
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", count);
            count++;
            img = fopen(filename, "w");

            fwrite(arr1, sizeof(BYTE), 512, img);
        }

        else if (arr1[0] != 0xff && arr1[1] != 0xd8 && arr1[2] != 0xff && (arr1[3] & 0xf0) != 0xe0 && count != 0)
        {
            fwrite(arr1, sizeof(BYTE), 512, img);
        }
        else if (arr1[0] == 0xff && arr1[1] == 0xd8 && arr1[2] == 0xff && (arr1[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0 && count != 0)
        {
            fclose(img);
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", count);
            count++;
            img = fopen(filename, "w");
            fwrite(arr1, sizeof(BYTE), 512, img);
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

My code correctly compiles and finds 50 images but says that images didn't match and says program isn't free of memory problems, can somebody help me with debugging?
check50 says

```
:) recover.c exists.
:) recover.c compiles.
:) handles lack of forensic image
:( recovers 000.jpg correctly
    recovered image does not match
:( recovers middle images correctly
    recovered image does not match
:( recovers 049.jpg correctly
    recovered image does not match
:| program is free of memory errors
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
```

Comment: You could clean up the loop a bit. The last `else continue` can be removed. The three `fwrite` lines can be replaced by one `fwrite` at the end of the loop, because you always need that. You only need to check if it's a header block once, not three times. Draw a simple little flow chart, based round `fread` and `fwrite`, and closing/opening the file when a header is found.

Comment: "says program isn't free of memory problems" No it does not. It says that it cannot check that while there are frowns. So you need to check your recovering calculations first. With that we can however not help, because you provide zero information on what the program is supposed to do for recovering. Note that there is a special cs50 community, which probably does not need you to do that explaining. So without that information, users here can probably not do better than recommending you to double check the frowns, possibly using a debugger.

Comment: The 2 else-if have identical condition?

Comment: Always check the file IO function return values! Even if no error "should" happen in a test environment, return value also conveys other information, and errors are always possible if _your_ code has issues. And, from the `:(` it seems it indeed has issues.

Comment: It is likely your `fread` returns unexpected value at some point, which should hint you about the nature of your bug.

Answer (score 0):

I could see two problems:

a) One reason for file content errors could be not opening the files in **binary mode**.

b) In this middle condition

```
else if (arr1[0] != 0xff && arr1[1] != 0xd8 && arr1[2] != 0xff && (arr1[3] & 0xf0) != 0xe0 && count != 0)
{
    fwrite(arr1, sizeof(BYTE), 512, img);
}
```

you will refuse to write a data block if *any* of the signature bytes matches. They are allowed to: all must match for the signature block, but for a data block any of them can match: but not *all* them

This code simplifies the logic. There is absolutely no need to check for the header block *three times*, or write to the output in three different places.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define BLOCKSIZE   512                     // don't repeat magic number
typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {                        // is simpler
        printf("Usage: ./recover IMAGE\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");      // use binary mode
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open input file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char filename[8];
    BYTE arr1[BLOCKSIZE];
    int count = 0;
    size_t bytes;                           // bytes read
    FILE *img = NULL;                       // initialise
    while ((bytes = fread(arr1, 1, BLOCKSIZE, file)) != 0)
    {
        if (arr1[0] == 0xff && arr1[1] == 0xd8 && arr1[2] == 0xff && (arr1[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0 && count == 0) 
        {
            // header block detected
            if (img != NULL)
            {
                fclose(img);
            }
            sprintf(filename, "%03d.jpg", count);
            count++;
            img = fopen(filename, "wb");    // use binary mode
            if (img == NULL)
            {
                printf("Could not open output file %s\n", filename);
                return 1;
            }

        }
        if (img != NULL)                    // first block might not be a header
        {
            fwrite(arr1, 1, bytes, img);    // do this once per loop
        }
    }
    
    if (img != NULL)
    {                                       // tidy up
        fclose(img);
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: The `fwrite` should be `if (img != NULL) fwrite(...)`. Most other SO answers for this cs50 question do this. This guards against the possibility that there is non-header data at the front of the input file. The actual data file for this problem _does_ have such non-header data at the front. It has 512 bytes of zeroes followed by `cs50.ly/surprise` padded with zeros to fill out another 512 bytes. The first actual `.jpg` header starts at offset 0x400.